# How I can cause a program in C to print only one statement once it encounters a specific condition?

Tags: arrays, c, command-line-arguments, cs50

I have been trying to write a C program where the user inputs a command-line argument and the program checks if it is all number digits or not. If that is true, the program simply reprints what the user put in. If that is false and there is at least one non-number mixed in, the program just prints the word "bad" once.

What I have come up so far consists of the program checking each character of the input individually. However, what ends up happening once I put in a mixture of numbers and letters in is that the program would still print the numbers, and then once it gets to printing a letter, it prints the word "bad".

Here's an example:

- I put `./program 100x` into the terminal

=> Expected result: bad

=> Actual result: 100bad

Here's the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) != 0) {
            printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("bad");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program terminates during the first time through the loop. All code paths execute a `return` statement. It either prints **one char** (and terminates) or the word **bad** (and terminates).

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. You said the program should check the input first and then decides whether the whole input is printed or the word bad is printed. But that is not what your actual program does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think your program is doing what your describe because it returns at the first digit encountered. Then, as soon as you see a digit you print it, you want to first check that your input is right and then print it. Taking your implementation, you could modify it like that:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    // checking input
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
        if (!(isdigit(argv[1][i]) != 0)) {
            printf("bad\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // here you know your input is good
    // prints input
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find readability dimishes with the explicit comparison `(!(isdigit(argv[1][i]) != 0))` vs `(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 //for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
     {
    //if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) != 0)
    if(strspn(argv[1], "0123456789" )== strlen(argv[1]))
        {
        printf("%s", argv[1]);
        return 0;
        }

     else
     {
         printf("bad");
         return 1;
     }
 }


 }
```

Comment: You don't really need to `for` loop (or the `i` variable) here

Answer (score 0):

Your logical error is that your program checks one character and immediately prints a digit or a bad message, and so continues with each character. However, you need to try writing an algorithm that first checks the whole string for characters other than numbers. If the algorithm finds at least one character (the result is false), it can close loop by using "break" keyword and print "bad" after. OR if all characters are numbers, you can return the value true and only then print them on the screen.